# Reactive Java List to Map

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a `methodA` which takes an argument and returns a result. I am writing a reactive method to invoke the function in bulk. But Not able to get my head around reactive syntax.
My code looks like this

```
List<GetResult> successfulResults = 
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
Map<String, Throwable> erroredResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch).flatMap(key -> reactiveCollection.getAndTouch(key, Duration.ofMinutes(extendExpiryInMin))
    .onErrorResume(e -> {
        erroredResults.put(key, e);
        return Mono.empty();
    })
).doOnNext(successfulResults::add).last().block();
```

The current implementation calls the method but collects the result in list. Collecting result in list does not make sense to my use case. I want to collect the result in a hashmap of key and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
List<String> docsToFetch = Arrays.asList("airline_112", "airline_1191", "airline_1203");

Map<String, GetResult> successfulResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Map<String, Throwable> erroredResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch).flatMap(key -> reactiveCollection.get(key).onErrorResume(e -> {
    erroredResults.put(key, e);
    return Mono.empty();
}).doOnNext(getResult -> successfulResults.put(key, getResult))).last().block();
```